# Distribution with closed-form expectation for multivariate "sigmoid"-type function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value

I was wondering whether anyone could think of a continuous distribution $F$, say,
such that there exists a closed-form expression (or something that does not require the numerical approximation of an $n$-dimensional integral) for the expectation of $$\dfrac{\exp(a_k+x_k)}{\sum_{i=1}^n\exp(a_i+x_i)}$$
where $1\leq k\leq n$, $\{a_i\}_{i=1}^n$ is a set of constants, and all random variables $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n$ are drawn from $F$ in an iid fashion.

Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't handle your constants $a_i$, but if the $\exp(x_k)$ are Gamma, the ratios $\exp(x_k)/\sum_i\exp(x_i)$ are [jointly Dirichlet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution#Related_distributions).

Comment: Many thanks for your reply! Unfortunately, the constants are indispensable for the application that I have in mind. I'll think a little bit about it, but since the result relies on all Gamma distributions having the same scale parameter, I am not too hopeful...